# dataTable plugin is not working it shows all records in one page i want only 10 per page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I used dataTable plugin to format my html table.But it is not displaying the result what i want.It shows all records instead of 10 records per page.i used iDisplayLength: 10 also but it does not work.

My Code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#count').DataTable({
           "pagingType": "full_numbers",
           "iDisplayLength": 10
         }
    );
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
  <table id="count">
                <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Quarter ID</th>
                    <th>Locality Name</th>
                    <th>Block</th>
                    <th>Floor</th>
                    <th>RB Type</th>
                    <th>Quarter Type</th>
                    <th>Quarter No</th>
                    <th>No of Rooms</th>
                    <th>Servant quarter</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
        require 'connection.php';
        $q8="select * from mstquarters";
        $q9=mysqli_query($con,$q8);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($q9)>=1)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q9))
            {
                ?>
                <?php
                $y=$row['blockId'];
                $q5="select * from mstblocks where blockId='$y'";
                $r5=mysqli_query($con,$q5);
                $r6=mysqli_fetch_array($r5);
                $r7=$r6['block'];

                $z=$row['localityId'];
                $q6="select * from mstlocalities where localityId='$z'";
                $s5=mysqli_query($con,$q6);
                $s6=mysqli_fetch_array($s5);
                $s7=$s6['localitySName'];

                ?>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['quarterId'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s7;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r7;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['floor'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['rbType'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quarterType'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quarterNo'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['noOfRooms'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['servantQuarter'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</html>
```

I already included javascript file,should i include more file for working properly?

Comment: you will able to see browser console? You will have some error there. check and tell

Comment: You need to put `<tbody></tbody>` outside while loop its works

Comment: Keep `<tbody>` outside the while loop.

Comment: javascript console gives you every information you need for debugging.

Comment: thanks a lot its working now.Thanks

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT  If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. *Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem is You are creating `<tbody>` inside `while()` which created wrong table structure.***

Put it outside of `while()` and you will good to go

Like this:-

```
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        require 'connection.php';
        $q8="select * from mstquarters";
        $q9=mysqli_query($con,$q8);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($q9)>=1)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q9))
            {
                ?>
                <?php
                $y=$row['blockId'];
                $q5="select * from mstblocks where blockId='$y'";
                $r5=mysqli_query($con,$q5);
                $r6=mysqli_fetch_array($r5);
                $r7=$r6['block'];

                $z=$row['localityId'];
                $q6="select * from mstlocalities where localityId='$z'";
                $s5=mysqli_query($con,$q6);
                $s6=mysqli_fetch_array($s5);
                $s7=$s6['localitySName'];

                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['quarterId'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s7;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r7;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['floor'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['rbType'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quarterType'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quarterNo'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['noOfRooms'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['servantQuarter'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok,i am new here

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT  it's ok. every-one have a fresh start here. You will learn day-by-day basis

Answer (score 0):

Try `"_iDisplayLength": 10` or add [jquery.dataTables.js](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js) to your project.

because `iDisplayLength` is in *jquery.dataTables.js*

Answer (score 0):

Use $_REQUEST["start"] and $_REQUEST["length"]
 $_REQUEST["start"] by default start with 0 and $_REQUEST["length"] set iDisplayLength below.
 $('#count').DataTable({
           "pagingType": "full_numbers",
           "iDisplayLength": 10
         }
Take two variable
$start=$_REQUEST["start"];
$length=$_REQUEST["length"];

And use here---- select * from mstquarters limit $start,$length

Answer (score 0):

NOthing change in jquery code

Add code in php file.

Take two variable

$start=$_REQUEST["start"]; $length=$_REQUEST["length"];

And use here---- select * from mstquarters limit $start,$length